# Manipulating Attributes of an XML Document

Tags: c#, xml

I have a XML document in the following general format:

```
<Alpha>
    <Beta>
        <Gamma>
            <Delta id="1">
                ...
            </Delta>
            <Delta id="2">
                ...
            </Delta>
            ...
         </Gamma>
    </Beta>
</Alpha>
```

I'm looking for a way to find all of the `Delta` elements (regardless of how many there are) and increase the value of the `id` attribute by a specific value, `x`, and then save the document. What's the fastest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest in terms of the shortest amount of code?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
foreach (var id in doc.Descendants("Delta").Attributes("id"))
{
    id.SetValue((int) id + 1);
}
doc.Save("test.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use LINQ to Xml (I.e what .net version are you using??). If so then this is pretty easy with Linq:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(source);
foreach (var deltaNode in doc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == "Delta"))
    deltaNode.SetAttributeValue("id", "Whatever");
```